# JavaFX Sun's InputEventUtils in JDK10

Tags: java, javafx, sun, java-module

I am trying to build a library under JDK 10. The library was made with JDK 8.

```
public DockEvent(Object source, EventTarget target, EventType<? extends DockEvent> eventType,
      double x, double y, double screenX, double screenY, PickResult pickResult, Node contents) {
    super(source, target, eventType);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.screenX = screenX;
    this.screenY = screenY;
    this.sceneX = x;
    this.sceneY = y;
    this.pickResult = pickResult != null ? pickResult : new PickResult(target, x, y);
    final Point3D p = InputEventUtils.recomputeCoordinates(this.pickResult, null);
    this.x = p.getX();
    this.y = p.getY();
    this.z = p.getZ();
    this.contents = contents;
  }
```

---

But I got a compilation error at this line:

```
final Point3D p = InputEventUtils.recomputeCoordinates(this.pickResult, null);
```

Java 9 new module system hides package com.sun.javafx.scene.input and I can't access recomputeCoordinates(PickResult, Object) static method from InputEventUtils. This is essential to create the event.


How can I get the same result without access to sun's packages ?

Comment: That's the danger of relying on internal APIs. Since `InputEventUtils` is a public class and you are using a public method you can use the `--add-exports` command line option when compiling _and_ running your code.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this approach for now. It's even better if I find another way of achieving this.